# In F#, what is the correct syntax to specify a DefaultValue?

Tags: types, f#, datacontract, datamember

In F#, what is the correct syntax to specify a DefaultValue on the DataContract?  For example, in the code below, how do I set the default value for address to "".

```
[<DataContract>]
type Geocode = 
    { [<field: DataMember(Name = "type")>]
    typeX : string 
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "address")>]
    address : string }
```

Comment: Posted my comment as an answer so the question can be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Records don't support default values for fields. You'll have to use a class and the `[<DefaultValue>]` attribute. You can read more in the [MSDN article on Explicit Fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469494.aspx).

Comment: Is this still the case ?